# Using a option to hold a value in php

Tags: php, html, sql

Using php I have manage to search and display the data i need. Now I wish for the user to be able to select a option from a drop down menu and click update. Now when I try this it doesn't update the data for some reason. Are you able to notice any errors in the code below? I have included small bits of relevant code from the php file. I'm using the 'value=1' so that when I click update the query updates using the number rather than the text as i want to update a different field than the output field. Any ideas?

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) { //once the update is click this updates the gametable with the adjusted information


$updatequery = "
UPDATE 
GameTable 
SET 
GameID='$_POST[gameid]', 
GameName='$_POST[gamename]', 
PubID='$_POST[Publisher]', 
TimePeriodID='$_POST[TimePeriod]', 

SettingID='$_POST[Setting]',    //the field i want to update using the value of the named select option

MoodID='$_POST[Mood]',
GameWeaponID='$_POST[Weapon]', 
GameCameraAngleID='$_POST[CameraAngle]', 
GamePlayerTypeID='$_POST[PlayerType]', 
GameDescription='$_POST[Description]' 
WHERE 
GameID='$_POST[gameid]'";

mysqli_query($dbcon, $updatequery);

echo "Record successfully updated";

};


//query that fetches data from a database and outputs. 

while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {
  echo "<tr> <th> Setting ID</th> </tr>";
  echo "<td><select class='text-black input-button-rounded' name='Setting'>";
  //the output is a different field to the one I want to update so that's why I want to use the value.
  echo               "<option disabled selected>" . $row5['SettingName'] . "</option>";
  echo               "<option class='text-black' type='text' value=1>Western</option> ";
  echo               "<option class='text-black' type='text' value=2>Space</option>";
  echo               "<option class='text-black' type='text' value=3>City</option>";
  echo               "<option class='text-black' type='text' value=4>Sea</option>";
  echo               "<option class='text-black' type='text' value=5>Apocalypse</option>";
  echo               "</select></td><br>";


//update button

  echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black input-button-rounded type=submit name=update value=Update" . " </td>";
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but in your html code, the <tr> elements contains your <th> but not your <td>

Comment: When referencing $_POST values, you should wrap the array keys in quotes, so $_POST['value'] rather than $_POST[value]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your `select` and submit button need to be wrapped in a `<form>` element, so that when the "Update" button is clicked, it POSTs the Setting data as well.

A few other things to note:

- All the quotes for the values of the HTML attributes are missing from the line which has your button code. Also the quotes for the array keys of `$_POST` in your SQL statement e.g. you wrote`$_POST[Mood]` rather than `$_POST['Mood']` Why is that?
- You don't need `type="text"` for the `option` tags.
- If you really want to build a secure website/app you shouldn't be using raw SQL statements. Rather, make use of either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) prepared statements.